# How to call a method simultaneously from multiple threads?

Tags: java, scala, jvm

I have an application that should (in some cases) guard against multiple threads. In order to have a test for that I need to call a method from multiple threads simultaneously at the same time.

```scala
class MyObject {

  val myMethodCalled = new AtomicBoolean()   

  def myMethod() = {

    if (myMethodCalled.getAndSet(true))
      throw new IllegalStateException("Do not call myMethod twice")
  }
}
```

I want to trigger the exception in the above method from a test case.

Is this possible in the `JVM`? If so, how to do it?

### Edit

I was wondering if there was any way (using some trick or a class I don't know) to call a method at the exact same time within the virtual machine. I guess that's not possible.

Comment: here's a hint, no test code is going to cause that exception to be generated.

Comment: That's not really helpful. Any reasoning to your statement?

Comment: I'm not an expert in scala, but isn't that variable just instantiated for each method call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should slow down the processing of your method by sleeping in the middle of it (`Thread.sleep`) or doing time-consuming busywork, and then have two or more other threads call that method as fast as they can.

You also can abstract out your run-only-once functionality so you can test it in isolation.  E.g.

```
def onlyOnce[A](f: => A) = {
  if (myMethodCalled.getAndSet(true)) throw new Exception("Twice!")
  f
}
```

and then when you need to test whether this in fact works, you pass in a slowly-executing `f` to make testing easy.  Otherwise, in your once-only methods you

```
def doSomething = onlyOnce {
}
```

which if you have tested `onlyOnce` properly will not go wrong (assuming things are properly encapsulated so that the body of `f` doesn't mess up the value of `myMethodCalled`).

Finally, your best bet otherwise is to use a machine with at least three real execution threads and have two of them do busywaiting where one flips a volatile var that the other is reading and then both run the method.  This is not inherently reliable, but if you have small busy-wait offsets between the two and cover the relevant space a bunch of times, you can at least make a statistical argument that you're okay at least almost all the time.

Comment: But the method is production code. It feels wrong to add a sleep argument just for testing. This must be something other developers of multi threaded applications have encountered.

Comment: @EECOLOR - You're running your test case in production?!  That sounds like a bad idea to me.  If not, the key to testing is to make it easy to generate the behavior you want.  You're lucky to be in a case where that's so easy!  Often the logic is much more complicated and you can't use such a simple strategy.

Comment: I am running my test cases *before* I deploy to production. If I follow your suggestion I would have to add an argument like this: `def myMethod(sleepBeforeCheck:Int = 0)`.

Comment: @EECOLOR - If this is the core of some high-performance routine then you should expect that your test code will not in fact be identical to your running code, as optimization (including optimizing away testability) is of prime importance.  Otherwise, I've edited my answer to give you a concrete suggestion for how to test the only-once capability.

Comment: I agree and like the approach of refactoring out using the `onlyOnce` version. For now I accept you answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your def to a lazy val and you can be garaunteed it will only run once:

```
object MyObject {

// static field
val myMethodCalled = new AtomicBoolean()   

// static method
lazy val myMethod = {
  if (myMethodCalled.getAndSet(true))
    throw new IllegalStateException("Do not call myMethod twice")
  }
}
```

Comment: his goal is to be able to run test code to cause the exception... not to avoid the exception

Answer (score 0):

I am a little puzzled by the need for the AtomicBoolean. Because you're using it, you *should* do the decent thing and write a test. That's good. However, testing threaded code is jolly hard on the JVM (and not particularly easy in other languages even without the JVM's handicaps).

Fortunately, there may be a simpler solution in your case. It seems you're perhaps trying to detect when a particular method has been accidentally used concurrently. Could you instead *prevent* it from being so used? For example:

```
class MyObject {
  def myMethod() {
    synchronized {
      .. stuff in here is serialized by the Hoare Monitor
    }
  }
}
```

An effective alternative strategy is to isolate sequential behaviour within a purpose-designed module. This is the general principle behind the actor pattern, and also the more general CSP algebra (used in Occam, Go, Limbo and available on the JVM via the JCSP API). Testing sequential code is generally much easier, so these patterns help you partition the task into manageable chunks.

There are at four concurrency failures that cannot be eliminated purely by testing alone, about which [I wrote an article a while ago](http://www.bigbeeconsultants.co.uk/blog/four-horsemen).

Comment: I was not actually looking for a solution of the problem, but checking if there was a way to test concurrency problems. You write in your article *Some developers make the mistake of trying to prove that their code does not have these problems by means of unit and functional testing.*. I guess I would be one of those. Do you have any information on how to approach this situation?

Comment: Yes and no. There has been some significant academic research that is not well known about, so I had planned to write some follow-up articles discussing this more. (eg. Martin & Welch "A Design Strategy for Deadlock-Free Concurrent Systems") Maybe this will spur me on to write more soon!